# Redirection from naked domain example.com to www.example.com fails

Tags: redirect, dns

I own a domain name that I have mapped with a Google blogger blog. I have set the option to redirect visits to example.com to www.example.com. I have bought the domain from GoDaddy, and in the DNS Zone File settings I have added CNAMES following the instructions provided by Google.

So typing www.example.com works and my blog gets opened. However, example.com doesn't work, it goes to a GoDaddy static page.

What do I do to get this working?

Cheers!
Bharath

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be in the A name associated with the domain name. I checked at http://www.digwebinterface.com/ and found that the A name added in my DNS Zone File was pointing to an incorrect address.

I added the correct address and the redirection started working as expected.